# Read multiple gzip files to 1 fileobject in python

Tags: python, file, gzip, python-2.x

i want to read multiple gzip file to 1 file object 
currently i am doing

```
import gzip 
a = gzip.open(path2zipfile1) 
for line in a.readline()
  #do some stuff
```

but i need to read from say 2 files

```
a = gzip.open(path2zipfile1)  #read zip1
a = gzip.open(path2zipfile2, 'rU') #appending file object with contents of 2nd file 
for line in a.readlines()
  #this should give me contents from zip1 then zip2
```

unable to find the right mode to do so

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
import itertools, gzip

files = ['path2zipfile1', 'path2zipfile2']
it = (gzip.open(f, 'rt') for f in files)

for line in itertools.chain.from_iterable(it):
    print(line)
```

another version without `itertools`:

```
def gen(files):
    for f in files:
        fo = gzip.open(f, 'rt')
        while True:
            line = fo.readline()
            if not line:
                break
            yield line

files = ['path2zipfile1', 'path2zipfile2']
for line in gen(files):
    print(line)
```

Comment: This works for me, can you tell what i was doing wrong and how itertools made it work. TIA

Comment: @pythonRcpp IMO [doc of `chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) explains better than me ... I would like to answer your question regarding the doc.

Comment: @pythonRcpp I added a version without `itertools`, which is mostly equivalent.

Comment: I realised I was supposed to use a.readlines() and not a.readline(). edited

Comment: @pythonRcpp I see, but the answer not affected.